# GreenDao Childrens' Parent Object References the Same Object Instance After Insert()

Tags: android, database, sqlite, session, greendao

I am using GreenDao and I have 1:N relationship between a RaceTrack and LapTime, a RaceTrack can have many LapTimes, a LapTime can only have 1 RaceTrack of course.

I list the top 5 LapTimes in a LinearLayout, all of these LapTime objects refer to a unique instance of a RaceTrack member field, this member field is set upon the first call of lapTime.getRaceTrack() and each RaceTrack is correctly set as expected on first call (see example below for clarity).

The issue lies when I add a new RaceTrack object to the database using raceTrackDao.insert(raceTrack). Upon inserting this new RaceTrack object, without explanation, all of the member fields for newly created LapTimes refer to the new instance of RaceTrack which was just inserted.

For example, the list of LapTimes and their RaceTrack member field id PRE-INSERT of the new RaceTrack object:

1. RaceTrack-5432 (created this session)
2. RaceTrack-5430 (created this session)
3. RaceTrack-5429 (existed in database before this session)
4. RaceTrack-5428 (existed in database before this session)

Now, the list of LapTimes and their RaceTrack member field id POST-INSERT of the RaceTrack object:

1. RaceTrack-5433 (created after insert(raceTrack), new RaceTrack object is 5433)
2. RaceTrack-5433 (created this session)
3. RaceTrack-5433 (created this session)
4. RaceTrack-5429 (existed in database before this session)
5. RaceTrack-5428 (existed in database before this session)

What is going on to change the previously initiated LapTime's member field to be equal to the newly inserted RaceTrack's instance?

Any help getting started would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any good ideas for debugging these fields becoming the same memory references?

Comment: Show your code please.